# Parsing an xml file using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to edit an xml file by finding each Watts tag and changing the text in it.  So far I've managed to change all tags, but not the Watts tag specifically.

My parser is:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("cycling.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for watt in root.iter():
    if watt.tag == "Watts":
        watt.text = "strong"

tree.write("output.xml")
```

This keeps my cycling.xml file unchanged.  A snippet from output.xml (which is also the cycling.xml file since this is unchanged) is:

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Biking">
      <Id>2018-05-06T20:49:56Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2018-05-06T20:49:56Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>2495.363</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>15345</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>18.4</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>0</Calories>
        <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
        <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
        <Track>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2018-05-06T20:49:56Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>49.319297</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-123.024128</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <HeartRateBpm>
              <Value>99</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Extensions>
              <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
                <Watts>0</Watts>
                <Speed>2</Speed>
              </TPX>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
```

If I change my parser to change all tags with:

```
for watt in root.iter():
    if watt.tag != "Watts":
        watt.text = "strong"
```

Then my output.xml file becomes:

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">strong<Activities>strong<Activity Sport="Biking">strong<Id>strong</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2018-05-06T20:49:56Z">strong<TotalTimeSeconds>strong</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>strong</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>strong</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>strong</Calories>
        <Intensity>strong</Intensity>
        <TriggerMethod>strong</TriggerMethod>
        <Track>strong<Trackpoint>strong<Time>strong</Time>
            <Position>strong<LatitudeDegrees>strong</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>strong</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <HeartRateBpm>strong<Value>strong</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Extensions>strong<TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">strong<Watts>strong</Watts>
                <Speed>strong</Speed>
              </TPX>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>strong<Time>strong</Time>
            <Position>strong<LatitudeDegrees>strong</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>strong</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>strong</AltitudeMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm>strong<Value>strong</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Extensions>strong<TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">strong<Watts>strong</Watts>
                <Speed>strong</Speed>
              </TPX>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
```

1. How can I change just the Watts tag?
2. I don't understand what the `root = tree.getroot()` does. I just thought I'd ask this question at the same time, although I'm not sure it matters in my particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document defines a default XML namespace.  Look at the `xmlns=` attribute at the end of the opening tag:

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
```

This means there is no element named "Watts" in your document; you will need to qualify tag names with the appropriate namespace.  If you print out the value of `watt.tag` in our loop, you will see:

```
$ python filter.py 
{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2}TrainingCenterDatabase
[...]
{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2}Watts
{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2}Speed
```

With this in mind, you can modify your filter so that it looks like
this:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("cycling.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for watt in root.iter():
    if watt.tag == "{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2}Watts":
        watt.text = "strong"

tree.write("output.xml")
```

You can read more about namespace handling in the [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).

Comment: Thank you. I had printed watt.tag but I wasn't sure what it was telling me, and I had difficulty understanding parts of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since you use two important words *edit xml* and you are using `lxml`, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (the XML transformation language) where you can define a namespace prefix and change *Watts* anywhere in document without looping. Plus, you can pass values into XSLT from Python!

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"              
               xmlns:doc="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- VALUE TO BE PASSED INTO FROM PYTHON -->
    <xsl:param name="python_value">

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ADJUST WATTS TEXT -->
    <xsl:template match="doc:Watts">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="$python_value"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python**

```
from lxml import etree

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = etree.parse("cycling.xml")
xsl = etree.parse('XSLT_Script.xsl')

# CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
transform = etree.XSLT(xsl)    

# RUN TRANSFORMATION WITH PARAM
n = etree.XSLT.strparam('Strong')
result = transform(doc, python_value=n)

# PRINT TO CONSOLE
print(result) 

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```